# Arrow in specific direction

Tags: opencv

I am trying to implement arrow formation at the ends of the video frame that i have to show the direction of the moving vehicles. I have no idea how to proceed. Do I have to use Frame Subtraction method. I am confused. I can't even upload the sample photo to show the output.

I am unable to find solution. Please help me out.
I have black and white background. I need to plot arrows in the black region. I am helpless.

Comment: Are you asking for a complete algorithm or you miss something in particular? try to divide your problem into subproblem

Comment: @Michele: It would be grateful if you provide me the algorithm.
What i want to perform is, as soon as the vehicle enters the frame, the arrow should be placed at that point. Same goes with the exit of vehicle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use latent svm detector with the car model to detect the car:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

Then you can use tracking to track the car. Once you've tracked it, you can know it's driving direction and then you can plot an arrow indicating this direction.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have mailed you the output that i have to implement.